# Wi-Fi does not work after restarting PC, airplane hardware mode

Tags: drivers, 18.04, ralink, airplane-mode

I restarted my PC, an ASUS X555L with Ubuntu 18.04.  No wifi network appears and airplane mode is activated.

Results:

```
 iwconfig

 enp5s0    no wireless extensions.
 lo        no wireless extensions.
 wlp4s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

then try to get

```
ifconfig

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::d3c0:1cba:20d9:be2d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:16:7e:8a:ef:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22089  bytes 20002856 (20.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17034  bytes 1936588 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 3445  bytes 302533 (302.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3445  bytes 302533 (302.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The first command you try is `sudo ifconfig wlp4s0f0 up`

as a result

```
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0f0 up

SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation impossible because radio frequency is off
```

I see problems with the radio frequency and tested with `rfkill`

```
rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I can unlock rf and it doesn't work with `sudo rfkill unblock all` and it still appears `Hard blocked: yes`

I wanted to see what network card I had, so ran

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8550G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
04:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
04:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

I also wanted to see my network card information

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DESACTIVADO     
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       fabricante: Ralink corp.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp4s0f0
       versión: 00
       serie: 54:35:30:82:7b:c5
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:17 memoria:ff910000-ff91ffff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:05:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp5s0
       versión: 0c
       serie: 40:16:7e:8a:ef:ab
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiai've been on ubuntu for a long time and i've never had a problem like this. i've searched in many forums and i can't find a solution yet. i tried everything.tion=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:ff800000-ff800fff memoria:d0000000-d0003fff
```

and one last command I tried to get more information was

```
lsmod


Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
amdgpu               4108288  0
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              208896  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
kvm_amd                94208  0
ccp                    90112  1 i've been on ubuntu for a long time and i've never had a problem like this. i've searched in many forums and i can't find a solution yet. i tried everything.kvm_amd
kvm                   651264  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
rt2800lib             126976  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              61440  5 rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800pci,rt2800lib
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
mac80211              847872  3 rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib,rt2800lib
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
cfg80211              704512  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
asus_wmi               32768  1 asus_nb_wmi
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
joydev                 28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
serio_raw              20480  0
k10temp                16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344  1
snd_hda_intel          49152  10
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
radeon               1454080  24
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ttm                   102400  2 amdgpu,radeon
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
drm_kms_helper        180224  2 amdgpu,radeon
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
drm                   491520  21 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,ttm
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
snd                    86016  31 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
asus_wireless          20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
psmouse               151552  0
r8169                  81920  0
sdhci_pci              45056  0
realtek                20480  1
cqhci                  28672  1 sdhci_pci
sdhci                  57344  1 sdhci_pci
i2c_piix4              28672  0
ahci                   40960  4
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  1 asus_wmi
```

I don't know how to operate the Wi-Fi and be able to disable airplane mode.

I've been using Ubuntu for a long time and I've never had a problem like this. I searched in many forums, but I can't find a solution yet. I tried everything.

Comment: Look for a hard switch or a BIOS setting. Hard Block is from there.

Comment: Hard switch should be `Fn`+`F2`.

Comment: pressing fn + f2 appears on the screen mode airplane hadrware

Answer (score 1):

Try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to turn off airplane mode.

If it doesn't help, run in a terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r asus_wireless
```

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r asus_wireless` command did not work